# Android Google Maps API V2: How to change my location icon?

Tags: android, mylocationoverlay

In Google Map API v1, I can change My Location icon by write a class extends MyLocationOverlay. But I don't know how to do it in Google API v2.
Please help me solve this issue.

Comment: Are you using now the Google API v2?

Comment: @Arman: He wrote it in his post

Comment: @Arman: Did you read my question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think, that v2 does not support custom location icon, but you can work-around it by disabling your location and setting up custom location listener, which adds/updates your custom groundoverlay on every location update.